AWS s3 permissions missing for replication rule although role has AmazonS3FullAccessPolicy
I am trying to create a replication rule for my S3 bucket. The role I am using has the AmazonS3FullAccessPolicy enabled, which should give me all permissions for any s3 operation on any resource:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

I still get the following Error, saying that i am missing the permission to use s3:PutReplicationConfiguration:
view image
Here is what I tried to solve this issue:

I checked for permission boundaries on my IAM role, but none is set.

I added a bucket policy to make sure this bucket allows the necessary action:


{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID:role/ROLE-NAME"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutReplicationConfiguration",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME"
        }
    ]
}


I  used the admin access to see if there are any Service Control Policies (SCPs) active, but all are disabled.

I looked through all the other IAM policies associated with my role to check for any "deny"-statements.



what does your Cloud Trail say about this Permission Issue API call event ? You may have a different Role than you think when doing the S3 operation ...
